# CodeIgniter Add Book & Categories

Tags: php, codeigniter

Ok here is what I want to do:

I have an add book form with certain elements such as title, description, author and image etc. In the add form I also have some checkboxes which are the categories the user wants to place the book in. So far, when the user clicks the add book button on the form, all the inputs are validated, the book information is inserted to the database and the image is uploading successfully.

Once all this has happened, **in the model** I am returning the book_id of the record which has just been added to the db and inserting it into another table, like this:

```
$book_id = $this->db->insert_id();
$data = array(
        'book_linktable_book_id' => $book_id,
    );
$this->db->insert('book_linktable', $data);
```

I need to insert the book_category_id into this other table along with the book_id. **So for each category the user has selected, insert the book_id and book_category_id into this other table.**

Here is the controller code:

```
function create_book(){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'trim|xss_clean|required|max_length[50]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', 'trim|xss_clean|required|max_length[600]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('exam_grade', 'Exam Grade', 'trim|xss_clean|required|max_length[10]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('author', 'Author', 'trim|xss_clean|required|max_length[25]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('edition', 'Edition', 'trim|xss_clean|required|max_length[15]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('publisher', 'Publisher', 'trim|xss_clean|required|max_length[30]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('price', 'Price', 'trim|xss_clean|required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $data = $this->style_model->admin_area();
        $data['category_query'] = $this->admin_books_model->get_book_categories();
        $data['page_title'] = 'Add New Book';
        $this->load->view('admin/books/add_book', $data);
    }
    else
    {           
        //upload the image and create thumbnail
        $config['upload_path'] = APPPATH . 'uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpeg|jpg|gif|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '1024';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        $field_name = "image";
        if( ! $this->upload->do_upload($field_name))
        {
            //failed to upload
            $data = $this->style_model->admin_area();
            $data['category_query'] = $this->admin_books_model->get_book_categories();
            $data['page_title'] = 'Add New Book';
            $this->form_validation->set_message("image", "Image size too large");
            $this->load->view('admin/books/add_book', $data);
        }
        else
        {
            //image uploaded
            $data = $this->input->post('category');
            $this->load->view('admin/category', $data);
            /*$upload_data = $this->upload->data('file_name');
            $image_name = $upload_data['file_name'];
            $this->admin_books_model->add_book($image_name);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'New Book Created');
            redirect('admin_books');*/
        }
    }   
} //function create_book()
```

Here is the model code:

```
function add_book($image_name){
    $data = array(
          'book_name' => $this->input->post('title'),
          'book_description' => $this->input->post('description'),
          'book_grade' => $this->input->post('exam_grade'),
          'book_author' => $this->input->post('author'),
          'book_edition' => $this->input->post('edition'),
          'book_publisher' => $this->input->post('publisher'),
          'book_price' => $this->input->post('price'),
          'book_image' => $image_name,
        );
    $this->db->insert('books', $data);

    $book_id = $this->db->insert_id();
    //for each category selected, getthe id and insert into link table


    $data = array(
        'book_linktable_book_id' => $book_id,
    );
    $this->db->insert('book_linktable', $data);
} //function add_book()
```

Here is the form code in the view:

```
<div id="left_form_content">
            <?php echo form_open_multipart('admin_books/create_book'); ?>
            <?php echo form_label('Title') . "<br />"; ?>
            <?php echo form_input('title', set_value('title')); ?>
            <?php echo form_error('title') . "<br />"; ?>
            <?php echo form_label('Exam Grade') . "<br />"; ?>
            <?php echo form_input('exam_grade', set_value('exam_grade')); ?>
            <?php echo form_error('exam_grade') . "<br />"; ?>
            <?php echo form_label('Edition') . "<br />"; ?>
            <?php echo form_input('edition', set_value('edition')); ?>
            <?php echo form_error('edition') . "<br />"; ?>
            <?php echo form_label('Author') . "<br />"; ?>
            <?php echo form_input('author', set_value('author')); ?>
            <?php echo form_error('author') . "<br />"; ?>
            <?php echo form_label('Publisher') . "<br />"; ?>
            <?php echo form_input('publisher', set_value('publisher')); ?>
            <?php echo form_error('publisher') . "<br />"; ?>
        </div>
        <div id="right_form_content">
            <?php echo form_label('Description') . "<br />"; ?>
            <?php echo form_textarea('description', set_value('description')); ?>
            <?php echo form_error('description') . "<br />"; ?>
            <?php echo form_label('Categories') . "<br />"; ?>
            <?php
                foreach($category_query as $data) {
                    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='category[]' value='" . $data->book_category_id . "'>" . $data->book_category_name . "</input>" . "<br />";
                }
            ?>          
            <?php echo form_error('categories') . "<br />"; ?>
            <?php echo form_label('Image') . "<br />"; ?>
            <?php echo form_upload('image', set_value('image')); ?>
            <?php echo form_error('image') . "<br />"; ?>
            <?php echo form_label('Price') . "<br />"; ?>
            <?php echo form_input('price', set_value('price')); ?>
            <?php echo form_error('price') . "<br />"; ?>
            <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Add Book'); ?>
            <?php echo form_close(); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help,

Tom

EDIT:

Here are the DB Tables:

```
Books
book_id
book_title
book_description
book_author
book_grade
book_edition
book_publisher
book_image
book_price

book_categories
book_category_id
book_category_name


book_linktable
    book_linktable_book_id
    book_linktable_book_category_id
```

Comment: put the schema of the tables. As of now, use an extra query to retrieve the category with reference to book_id (you'l need JOIN statement). Then insert the both.

Comment: Thank you for the reply itachi, Ahh I understand what your saying ill give it a try, and I will put the scheme up now

Comment: Ohh and also it might be worth noting, on the add form, the checkboxes are pulled fromm the db which means I have already got their id's, they are echoed in a form_hidden() field. Can I not pass those selected category_id's to the model rather than doing another query?

Comment: A book can have multiple category or only one category? The point i am asking here is, are those checkboxes multiselect or only single select?

Comment: Yes. A book can have multiple categories, on the add form the user can choose whether the book belongs to just one category or it may belong to more than one for example it could be a love story but it may also apply to the 'books for females' category. The checkboxes are single checkboxes, one for each category, there is a loop and for each category in the query it echos the book_category_id in a form_hidden() and then the book_category_name as the value of the checkbox. Do you think I have done the checkboxes incorrectly/should they be done in a different way?

Comment: actually i am not seeing the point of why you need `book_linktable`. 2 tables are enough for this purpose.

Comment: I need the linktables for later on in the development, but for now I need to know how to: for each category that is selected in the checkboxes, inserti it into the db table along with the book_id

Comment: I've moved on a little more now with this. I am capturing the id's of the selected checkboxes and passing them to the model in an array. now in the model all I need to do is repeat the same db query for each Id in the array. Would you know anything about this?

so my query is this:

`$data = array(`
  `'book_linktable_book_id' => '$book_id',`
  `'book_linktable_book_category_id' => '$book_category_id',`
`);`
`$this->db->insert('book_linktable', $data);`

I need to repeat this query for each category_id I have in my array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be pretty close from what you're trying to accomplish. You just need to iterate through the array of the category IDs and insert the rows like this:

```
$categories = $this->input->post('category');
foreach ($categories as $category_id)
{
    $this->db->insert('book_linktable', array(
        'book_linktable_book_id' => $book_id,
        'book_linktable_book_category_id' => $category_id
    ));
}
```

Alternatively, you can also use the `insert_batch()` method.

```
$data = array();
foreach ($categories as $category_id)
{
    $data[] = array('book_linktable_book_id' => $book_id,
                    'book_linktable_book_category_id' => $category_id
    );
}
$this->db->insert_batch('book_linktable', $data);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I appreciate you taking the time to read a hell of a lot of info! I'll try now and report back what I find!!

Comment: Its saying invalid argument supplied for the foreach, does this have anything to do with me trying to do this in the model?

Comment: Hi Kemal, I have used your first solution and I have now got it working! I ran a few different tests and turns out I wasnt passing the array to the model correctly but now I have tested it and it is functioning exactly as I want. Thanks for your help really appreciate it.